# Missing return in a function expected to return ‘String’

Tags: swift

I’m writing swift code for BMI calculator, why does error “Missing return in a function expected to return ‘String’ “ will happen? Does anyone can explain the reason of this? Thank you!

```
func bmiCalculator (weight: Double, height: Double) -> String {
    let bmi = weight / (height * height)

    if bmi > 25 {
        return "Your BMI is \(bmi). You are overweight"
    } else if bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 25 {
    return "Your BMI is \(bmi). You are at a normal weight"
    } else if bmi < 18.5 {
        return "Your BMI is \(bmi). You are underweight"
    }
}

print(bmiCalculator(weight: 70, height: 1.74))
```

I expect Xcode playground will calculate the BMI based on weight and height value on the last line, but it shows error "Missing return in a function expected to return ‘String’"

Answer (score 1):

Although it looks like you have complete coverage of the values here, so any else wouldn’t actually be possible, the syntax is being checked without fully analyzing the context. It expects to still be able to know for sure that it has all returns ending with a `String` result.

```
func bmiCalculator (weight: Double, height: Double) -> String {
    let bmi = weight / (height * height)

    if bmi > 25 {
        return "Your BMI is \(bmi). You are overweight"
    } else if bmi < 18.5 {
        return "Your BMI is \(bmi). You are underweight"
    }
    return "Your BMI is \(bmi). You are at a normal weight"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method has to return `String` value, but you're missing return value for case when none condition is true: `else {...}`

There are three possible situations:

> bmi > 25
>
> bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 25
>
> bmi < 18.5

... so good practice would be using `switch` statement

```
switch bmi {
case 25.nextUp...:
    return "Your BMI is \(bmi). You are overweight"
case ..<18.5:
    return "Your BMI is \(bmi). You are underweight"
default:
    return "Your BMI is \(bmi). You are at a normal weight"
}
```

Comment: `switch bmi {` 
`case 25...:`
    `print("Your BMI is \(bmi). You are overweight")` 
`case 18.5...25:` 
   `print("Your BMI is \(bmi).. You are at a normal weightt")`
`default:`
   `print( "Your BMI is \(bmi) You are underweigh")` 
`}`

Comment: @LeoDabus isn't `25...` acutally `>= 25`? And shouldn't `default` case be the most common case (normal weight)?

Comment: You can use `25.nextUp...`

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you! I didn't know about this option! :-)